# How to deploy and run window service in AWS for cron jobs?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, cron

I wanted to run .NET window service/c# script as background process in AWS and I'm very new for AWS, So if anybody can suggest that how can I schedule my window service over the AWS to execute it every day based on time set?

Comment: What about [AWS Lambda with scheduled events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)?

Comment: @john Thanks for your reply, but as I think there is a time limit on Lambda functions is 5 minutes and my script required much more time then that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to test and develop you C# windows server locally, and then use RDP to connect to the EC2 instance and re-install it there.

There is nothing special about running an EC2 instance - its just another Windows server (in this case) that you can install whatever you want on it.

Thats the basic minimum you need to do; of course, once you learn more about AWS there is probably a lot more you could do, i.e. setup automated deployments so that when you update your service it gets deployed automatically, autoscaling it, load-balancing it, taking snapshots and backing it up etc -

But, just to get up and running, just install the windows service like you would on any other windows machine and you can build from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you means I need to deploy window service in my local machine and then I can upload it to EC2 using RDP,  right?

Comment: No, I mean get it all working on your local machine for testing purposes - and then take a copy of the windows service and install it on the EC2 instance - the install process will be the same.

Comment: Okay, just another question - Could we run cron jobs on AWS by any other way? Like if I will build the node.js app and then run it based on cron settings?

Comment: @Brennan, Could you please suggest me the best tutorial to create a cron job for windows service?